# Five equations to solve 6-variables question, is it possible?

Tags: equation-solving, variable

I was given a task to find the value of variable a,b,c,d,e and f. But I'm not sure it is even possible, given that only 5 equations are available. Can anybody point out how to solve these:

```
a+b+c=164.35;
d+e+f=94.44; 
a^2+d^2=20.06^2; 
b^2+e^2=74.34^2; 
c^2+f^2=123.27^2
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT 1:**

If you know additional constraints for each variable, you can add them in to the list of equations.

```
sols = Solve[{
           a + b + c == 164.35, 
           d + e + f == 94.44, 
           a^2 + d^2 == 20.06^2, 
           b^2 + e^2 == 74.34^2, 
           c^2 + f^2 == 123.27^2, 
           a >= 0, 
           b >= 0, 
           c >= 0, 
           d >= 0, 
           e >= 0, 
           f >= 0
         }, 
         {a, b, c, d, e, f}, 
         Reals
       ]
sols[[3]]
(* {a->19.7827,b->23.001,c->121.566,d->3.32366,e->70.6922,f->20.4241} *)
```

`sols[[3]]` remains relatively simple, however the first 2 are still rather complicated expressions.

**Original:**

If you look up `Solve` or `NSolve` in the documentation centre, it should demonstrate some basic examples of how to use those functions.

```
sols = Solve[{
           a + b + c == 164.35, 
           d + e + f == 94.44, 
           a^2 + d^2 == 20.06^2, 
           b^2 + e^2 == 74.34^2, 
           c^2 + f^2 == 123.27^2
         }, 
         {a, b, c, d, e, f}, 
         Reals
       ]
```

The first 7 solutions returned are complicated `ConditionalExpressions`, but if you look as `sols[[8 ;; 17]]`, those are fairly simple solutions with a numerical value for each of the variables. Of course, I'm assuming you're only looking for answers where all $a$ through $f$ are real. If that's not the case, you can drop the `Reals` part from the `Solve` command.

In general, there are many values of $a, b, c, d, e,$ and $f$ that satisfy the equations. I don't know if you have any further constraints, or if you simply need *some* solution.

Comment: Wow thanks. This is great. Yes, a through f are real values, but I forgot to mention that the values are positive number. Is there a way to add this constraint inside this?

Another question is, the value may be a positive number, but it can also be zero, is there any way to represent my statement here?

Thanks again.

Comment: @Azlan No problem. I've updated by answer to include your conditions.

Comment: Great, thanks! This definitely solves my problem.

Comment: @Azlan Note that your intuition was correct: in general it is _not_ possible to solve $n$ variables with only $n-1$ equations. In many cases, you would still be able to _reduce_ complicated expressions to arrive at a _family_ of solutions. Take, for example ``Reduce[{x+y+z==2,x+y==1},{x,y,z},Reals]`` which gives $z=1$ and $y=1-x$. This last part describes a line of points for which the equations hold.

Comment: @LBogaardt thanks for your comments, I was thinking about some similar argument when I got the assignment thus I came to ask the question here, in case anybody have any better idea. However, by applying the code that MassDefect has shown above, the answer did come out (with a few warnings). Further, by applying a few conditions, I can get one single answer that fits all of the equations and conditions. I believe (my assumption) Mathematica did go beyond reasonable measure to get that answer ie. "trial and error", which I am so thankful that I get to apply my theory on the assignment.